# Undefined vars passing from qsub to shell script

Tags: bash, matlab, shell, qsub

I have a script like this that I run in terminal:

```
  for iter in 1
  do
    echo FullFilePath.sh $iter | qsub -V -e ~/pbs/ -o ~/pbs/
  done
```

In the shell file, it looks like this:

```
matlab -nosplash -singleCompThread -nojvm -r "a=${iter}"
```

It runs fine until it errors executing the matlab code above, with the error that I had an incorrect use of '=' operator: "a=". Basically $iter was undefined when the matlab script ran. I've tried so many versions and small edits to the above lines of code and it always errors... would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `export` your `iter` variable before executing your script.

```
export iter
```

So your script might look like:

```
for iter in {1..5}
do
    export iter
    sh FullFilePath.sh $iter | qsub -V -e ~/pbs/ -o ~/pbs/
done
```

Or you could add a line into your `FullFilePath.sh` to set the variable to your argument (`$1`):

```
iter=$1
```

Comment: Ah, this is what I needed. Thanks very much!!